# feature stapling in site definition

Tags: feature, site-definition, feature-stapling

I want to create site definition using VS2010, also when any site get created it should activate few feature automatically. How to use feature stapling exactly , please anyone let me know step by step I am newbie im sharepoint

Comment: You need to follow option 3 in this post http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2007/05/feature-stapling.html

Comment: I'm wondering why feature stappling when one of the possibilities in using site definitions is to actually specify which features to activate -simply listing these there would do the job. I would recomand you go for Web Templates though!

Comment: Hi Marius,

If I create 1 site definition and later create web template based on site definition. Means when i create web template specific feature get auto active. How to acheive this

Comment: Before anything else - Web Templates are preferred going forward. Than, as per your question - already specifying in the Features element the list of those features to be automatically activated in the Site Definition would already achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technical Details

Feature stapling is implemented through a Feature that is specifically designed to staple other Features to one or more site definitions. Feature stapling allows a Feature to be stapled to any new sites created from any site definition or from specific site definitions based on the template name identified in the appropriate WEBTEMP.xml file.

Feature Stapling has two features. A "Stapler" feature which staples another feature to the site definition and the "Staplee" feature which will be stapled. Let's take an example to understand it.

Scenario: You want to have custom list added to all of the "Team site" site definitions. This can be solved by creating a feature which will add the Custom list to the site and it can be associated with the Team site's site definition.

How to associate feature with sites / site definition?

A Feature can be associated with the sites / site definition in three different ways:

1. You can create a site from that site definition and deploy your "custom list" feature to the site and activate it.
2. If you already know all the required customizations before creating the site, you can include the features in the site definition (onet.xml) before you use it to create sites.
3. If you want to automatically provision your feature when the user creates the site & you don't want to include it in the  or  child elements of the  element that represents the site definition configuration, you can use Feature Stapling. Another reason would be when you want to do customization on out of the box site definitions, use of Feature Stapling.

This is my article which explains Feature stapling in SharePoint 2010. Please read through and this will be useful.

[Customization of Site Definition & what is the best way to do that?](http://tech.just4sharing.com/Pages/tech/Feature-Stapling-in-SharePoint-2010.aspx)

Comment: Please add at least a one liner comment when you down vote an answer. Really discouraging to see an accepted post is down voted.

Comment: Can you please try to add details from your blog post to your answer? We do not really approve answers containing no useful information other than a link

Comment: updated with details. The blog is very big and I added couple of paragraphs.

Comment: Looks much better :)

Answer (score 3):

Feature stappling simply means having a list of features to activate everytime a certain site definition is used (or in natural language stating "Do activate these features when any of the Site definition ID is created").

Basically there is always a Stappler (the actual feature linking one or more site definion ID with the actual features) and a Staplee (the actual feature identifier of the feature to activate).

In your case though, i'm thinking why not directly use the section dedicated to features ( - for site collection related features, and  for each sub-site - including the top-level) to simply specify there? i do understand for future flexibility might be one case, but if you only plan to activate certain features only for your Site Definition, i would say - no need for Stappling (it simply hides away some of inner-workings - which in longer term might make difficult to figure out what is going on, and debugging difficult)!

Answer (score 1):

You must create site definition and then add some part of text to onet.xml file look at  `<SiteFeatures>` and `<WebFeatures>` part :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project Title="SiteDefinitionTitle" Revision="2" ListDir="$Resources:core,lists_Folder;" xmlns:ows="Microsoft SharePoint">
  <NavBars>
    <NavBar Name="$Resources:core,category_Top;" Separator="&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;" Body="&lt;a ID='onettopnavbar#LABEL_ID#' href='#URL#' accesskey='J'&gt;#LABEL#&lt;/a&gt;" ID="1002" />
    <NavBar Name="$Resources:core,category_Documents;" Prefix="&lt;table border='0' cellpadding='4' cellspacing='0'&gt;" Body="&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;&lt;table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;&lt;img src='/_layouts/images/blank.gif' id='100' alt='' border='0'&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td valign='top'&gt;&lt;a id='onetleftnavbar#LABEL_ID#' href='#URL#'&gt;#LABEL#&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;/table&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;" Suffix="&lt;/table&gt;" ID="1004" />
    <NavBar Name="$Resources:core,category_Lists;" Prefix="&lt;table border='0' cellpadding='4' cellspacing='0'&gt;" Body="&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;&lt;table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;&lt;img src='/_layouts/images/blank.gif' id='100' alt='' border='0'&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td valign='top'&gt;&lt;a id='onetleftnavbar#LABEL_ID#' href='#URL#'&gt;#LABEL#&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;/table&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;" Suffix="&lt;/table&gt;" ID="1003" />
    <NavBar Name="$Resources:core,category_Discussions;" Prefix="&lt;table border='0' cellpadding='4' cellspacing='0'&gt;" Body="&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;&lt;table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;&lt;img src='/_layouts/images/blank.gif' id='100' alt='' border='0'&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td valign='top'&gt;&lt;a id='onetleftnavbar#LABEL_ID#' href='#URL#'&gt;#LABEL#&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;/table&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;" Suffix="&lt;/table&gt;" ID="1006" />
  </NavBars>
  <ListTemplates>
  </ListTemplates>
  <DocumentTemplates>
    <DocumentTemplate Path="STS" Name="" DisplayName="$Resources:core,doctemp_None;" Type="100" Default="FALSE" Description="$Resources:core,doctemp_None_Desc;" />
    <DocumentTemplate Path="STS" DisplayName="$Resources:core,doctemp_Word97;" Type="101" Description="$Resources:core,doctemp_Word97_Desc;">
      <DocumentTemplateFiles>
        <DocumentTemplateFile Name="doctemp\word\wdtmpl.doc" TargetName="Forms/template.doc" Default="TRUE" />
      </DocumentTemplateFiles>
    </DocumentTemplate>
    <DocumentTemplate Path="STS" DisplayName="$Resources:core,doctemp_Excel97;" Type="103" Description="$Resources:core,doctemp_Excel97_Desc;">
      <DocumentTemplateFiles>
        <DocumentTemplateFile Name="doctemp\xl\xltmpl.xls" TargetName="Forms/template.xls" Default="TRUE" />
      </DocumentTemplateFiles>
    </DocumentTemplate>
    <DocumentTemplate Path="STS" DisplayName="$Resources:core,doctemp_Powerpoint97;" Type="104" Description="$Resources:core,doctemp_Powerpoint97_Desc;">
      <DocumentTemplateFiles>
        <DocumentTemplateFile Name="doctemp\ppt\pptmpl.pot" TargetName="Forms/template.pot" Default="TRUE" />
      </DocumentTemplateFiles>
    </DocumentTemplate>
    <DocumentTemplate Path="STS" DisplayName="$Resources:core,doctemp_Word;" Type="121" Default="TRUE" Description="$Resources:core,doctemp_Word_Desc;">
      <DocumentTemplateFiles>
        <DocumentTemplateFile Name="doctemp\word\wdtmpl.dotx" TargetName="Forms/template.dotx" Default="TRUE" />
      </DocumentTemplateFiles>
    </DocumentTemplate>
    <DocumentTemplate Path="STS" DisplayName="$Resources:core,doctemp_Excel;" Type="122" Description="$Resources:core,doctemp_Excel_Desc;">
      <DocumentTemplateFiles>
        <DocumentTemplateFile Name="doctemp\xl\xltmpl.xlsx" TargetName="Forms/template.xlsx" Default="TRUE" />
      </DocumentTemplateFiles>
    </DocumentTemplate>
    <DocumentTemplate Path="STS" DisplayName="$Resources:core,doctemp_Powerpoint;" Type="123" Description="$Resources:core,doctemp_Powerpoint_Desc;">
      <DocumentTemplateFiles>
        <DocumentTemplateFile Name="doctemp\ppt\pptmpl.pptx" TargetName="Forms/template.pptx" Default="TRUE" />
      </DocumentTemplateFiles>
    </DocumentTemplate>
    <DocumentTemplate Path="STS" DisplayName="$Resources:core,doctemp_OneNote;" Type="111" Description="$Resources:core,doctemp_OneNote_Desc;">
      <DocumentTemplateFiles>
        <DocumentTemplateFile Name="doctemp\onenote\template.onepkg" TargetName="Forms/template.onepkg" Default="TRUE" />
      </DocumentTemplateFiles>
    </DocumentTemplate>
    <DocumentTemplate Path="STS" DisplayName="$Resources:core,doctemp_FP;" Type="102" Description="$Resources:core,doctemp_FP_Desc;">
      <DocumentTemplateFiles>
        <DocumentTemplateFile Name="doctemp\fp\fptmpl.htm" TargetName="Forms/template.htm" Default="TRUE" />
      </DocumentTemplateFiles>
    </DocumentTemplate>
    <DocumentTemplate Path="STS" DisplayName="$Resources:core,doctemp_BasicPage;" Type="105" Description="$Resources:core,doctemp_BasicPage_Desc;">
      <DocumentTemplateFiles>
        <DocumentTemplateFile Name="doctemp\blankpgs\_basicpage.htm" TargetName="Forms/_basicpage.htm" Default="TRUE" />
      </DocumentTemplateFiles>
    </DocumentTemplate>
    <DocumentTemplate Path="STS" DisplayName="$Resources:core,doctemp_WebPartPage;" Type="106" Description="$Resources:core,doctemp_WebPartPage_Desc;">
      <DocumentTemplateFiles>
        <DocumentTemplateFile Name="doctemp\smartpgs\_webpartpage.htm" TargetName="Forms/_webpartpage.htm" Default="TRUE" />
      </DocumentTemplateFiles>
    </DocumentTemplate>
    <DocumentTemplate XMLForm="TRUE" Path="STS" DisplayName="$Resources:core,doctemp_BlankForm;" Type="1000" Default="TRUE" Description="$Resources:core,doctemp_BlankForm_Desc;">
      <DocumentTemplateFiles>
        <DocumentTemplateFile Name="doctemp\xmlforms\blank\template.xml" TargetName="Forms/template.xml" Default="TRUE" />
      </DocumentTemplateFiles>
    </DocumentTemplate>
  </DocumentTemplates>
  <Configurations>
    <Configuration ID="0" Name="SiteDefinitionTemplateName">
      <Lists />
      <SiteFeatures>
        <!-- Site collection level Feature  Name-->
        <Feature ID="GUID of your feature" />
      </SiteFeatures>
      <WebFeatures>
        <!-- Web level Feature  Name-->
       <Feature ID="GUID of your feature" />
      </WebFeatures>
    </Configuration>
  </Configurations>
  <ServerEmailFooter>$Resources:ServerEmailFooter;</ServerEmailFooter>
</Project>
```

Comment: what does `XMLForm` attribute mean?

Comment: XMLForm
Optional Boolean. TRUE if the document template applies to a form library. Link to MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms411227.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use Site definitions and use Web templates instead, because of future upgrades and the fact that MS no longer support site definitions . In case you have custom features, you could write them at proper places in the onet.xml file. Association of you custom feature to onet.xml can be done easily as you might know from site definition development. Read this [MSDN manual](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vesku/archive/2010/10/14/sharepoint-2010-and-web-templates.aspx#webtemplate) as a jump start to the world of Web Templates.

Happy SharePointing!